# How to generate GET request to webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag

Tags: ios6, passbook, get-request

After creating a pass, I can add it to device, register device by saving data to database. Next, how can I generate GET request to webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag ? I see this in console:
 `Apr  4 10:08:26 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[12098] <Warning>: Generating GET request with URL <http:/192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/v1/devices/02d6566cc59dc34e3abd116eed498898/registrations/pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest>`
`Apr  4 10:08:26 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[12098] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device 02d6566cc59dc34e3abd116eed498898, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) got response with code 200`
`Apr  4 10:08:26 CamMobs-iPod4 passd[12098] <Warning>: Get serial #s task (for device 02d6566cc59dc34e3abd116eed498898, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated (null); with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (Missing response data)`

Comment: You don't "generate" the GET request, the device generates it.  You need to configure your web service to recognise the request, then query your database and return a list of relevant serial numbers, or if there are no serials that need updating, return with a `204` response.  You can take the same code you use to catch the registration and adapt it for this method (and the remaining 3 methods in the web service specification (unregister, deliver new pass and log).

Comment: why last updated (null) ?

Comment: Because when the device first received the pass, it did not receive a Last-Modified header.  If it had received a header, then it would request serials modified since that date.  The device will never know if the pass it has just installed is the freshest version so it will always call your web service to check whenever it installs a new pass.

Comment: how to set last-modified header ?

Comment: So I need to select serial from my pass in database ?

Comment: All depends on how you are serving your .pkpass file.  If using PHP then something like `header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/path/to/pass.pkass')) . ' GMT');`. If you want to set in Apache, then use `mod_expires` and set something like `ExpiresDefault modification plus 1 hour` in your httpd-config.  You could have probably found this on Google faster than the time it took me to type this though!

Comment: I use php, so I set like this :  header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass')) . ' GMT');

Comment: Assuming you are storing the last modified time in your database then yes, you should be querying and returning all serials relevant to that device ID for that require updating.  If you have the device ID and pass last updated times in different tables then you may need a JOIN query or have to do two queries to respond to this request.

Comment: if I want to update contents in a pass, so I add new row in that table or ,.... ?

Comment: For your header, yes - but replace GMT with the timezone of your server.

Comment: my code for GET request is like this: if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET"){
 header('Last-Modified: ' . date("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/DigiClubCard.pkpass')) . ' GMT+07:00');
 
 include("connectdb.php");
 $querySelect = mysql_query("select * from digiCardPass");
    
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($querySelect);
 if($serial == $row['serialNo']){
  
 }
}

Comment: but I am not sure what I want to respond for this request ?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988) is very clear.  A JSON dictionary containing an array of serials and a last updated tag e.g. `{"serialNumbers":["abc123", "def455"],"lastUpdated":"1365057662"}`.  In your case though, the pass has not changed so just send back a `204` header.

Comment: Also in you code, you should not be sending back a last modified header with this response.  The last modified header should be sent when the .pkpass bundle is first sent to the device.  Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "GET"` is also no sufficient because the "Getting the latest version of a pass" method also uses a GET request.

Comment: lastUpdated = timestamp ?

Comment: Read the docs!! - it can be whatever you like, but a timestamp would be the easiest to implement - just note that is should be sent as a string, not an int.